# How to make nested infinite v-for in vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

this is what i have tried

Html

```
<ul class="tree">
   <li>
   <span>First Node</span>
   <ul>
      <li v-for="(tree, i) in trees" :key="i">
      <span v-text="tree.name"></span>
      <ul v-if="tree.childrens">
            <li v-for="(child, j) in tree.childrens" :key="j">
                  <span v-text="child.name"></span>
            </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

I wanna loop every children without adding a new HTML element, but I have no idea how to do that.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      trees: [
        { name: 'Node A' },
        { name: 'Node B', childrens: [
            { name: 'Node B1' },
            { name: 'Node B2', childrens: [
                { name: 'Node B2.1' },
                { name: 'Node B2.2' },
            ] },
        ] },
      ],
    };
  },
};
```

Display

[image]

Anyone, thanks for your help

Comment: Make each `li` its own component and pass the children as props.

Comment: Vue v2 docs covered this in [Recursive Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html?redirect=true#Recursive-Components) but I found another that's more detailed: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-recursive-components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this requirement by using [`Circular References Between Components`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html?redirect=true#Recursive-Components) concept of Vue. Where instead of creating a separate element for each children you can recursively call the child component.

Live Demo **:**

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['children'],
  template: `<ul>
  <li v-for="(child, index) in children" :key="index">
    <parent v-if="child.childrens" :trees="[child]"></parent>
    <span v-else>{{ child.name }}</span>
  </li>
</ul>`
});

Vue.component('parent', {
  props: ['trees'],
  template: `<ul>
    <li v-for="(tree, i) in trees" :key="i">
      <span v-text="tree.name"></span>
      <child v-if="tree.childrens" :children="tree.childrens"></child>
    </li>
  </ul>`
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    trees: [
      { name: 'Node A' },
      { name: 'Node B', childrens: [
        { name: 'Node B1' },
        { name: 'Node B2', childrens: [
          { name: 'Node B2.1' },
          { name: 'Node B2.2' },
        ] },
      ] },
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <parent :trees="trees"></parent>
</div>
```